# Question about subject-verb agreement

Tags: word-usage, homework

Is this a run-on?

> By 1990, it was even easier to make bottles and paper products quickly; as a result, competition among companies grew and stores featured products with increasingly interesting and colorful labels.

Independent clauses: 
(1) competition among companies grew 
(2) stores featured products with increasingly interesting and colorful labels

So, is the sentence correct, or should there be a comma before the 'and'?

Also,

> Pancakes, perhaps the standard American breakfast, **are** losing a rapidly increasing number of calorie-conscious adherents.

Shouldn't the 'are' be 'is' because 'Pancakes' is singular because one eats pancakes and not a pancake? I don't know. 
These questions were from the Princeton Review 11 Practice Tests for the SATs book.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Most or at least many style books would recommend a comma after *grew* in your first sentence. As to the second sentence, I would say both plural and singular are OK, because you simply say *pancakes are*, or treat it like the name of a (single) dish and say *pancakes is*.

Comment: Why would one not eat a pancake if one ate only a single one? And why would the fact that one eats pancakes make ‘pancakes’ singular? One also gazes at the stars or picks up the pieces—but surely you'll agree that there are more than one star in the sky, and there'd be little point in picking up the pieces if there were only one piece.

Comment: Ok, so the first one is a run-on because it needs the comma after grew to seperate the independent clauses? And the second can be either plural or singular?

Comment: @JBJ: In the UK, notional agreement is standard: _Bacon and eggs, the traditional English breakfast, is losing a rapidly increasing number of calorie-conscious adherents._

Comment: As Cerberus notes, there is not a clear answer to pancakes is/are.  In these cases, the SAT cannot frame a test item around the concept, because it will not validate.*  For the same reason, SAT also rarely tests comma placement except in the case of really egregious errors.   "My brother, Tom likes to be called Tommy," or something equally and obviously wrong might show up.  The various reviews are often quite helpful, but may be overly strict.

Comment: Remember, the review are written and edited by a handful of people, the SAT is written and edited by another handful of people, and then it is submitted to thousands of high schoolers who, if they score well on the validated section of the test, then have to agree on the answers before the test items actually begin to count toward your score.

Comment: * Regarding the term "validate."  Test items are initially used in the SAT and ACT, but do not count toward the score until they are proven valid and reliable.  For example, a test item might assure that a candidate would know that electrical costs are higher in the winter because of high heating costs.  Such an item might fail to validate regionally . . . in South Florida, Southern California and Hawaii.

Comment: @Edwin, that is slightly different. ‘Bacon and eggs’ is a single unit and is grammatically singular, as are even ‘bangers and chips’, even though everything it consists of is plural. Pancakes, on the other hand, are grammatically plural. Even if you do use notional agreement with pancakes (which sounds strange to me: “Pancakes is losing adherents”?), that still doesn't make ‘pancakes’ singular—it just makes them take singular agreement.

Comment: @Janus From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun): <<... in [ ] English... , singular verb forms can often be used with nouns ending in "-s" that were once considered plural (for example: "Physics is my favorite academic subject"). This apparent "number mismatch" is actually a quite natural and logical feature of human language, and its mechanism is a subtle metonymic shift in the thoughts underlying the words.>> There are quite a few examples on the web of 'pancakes' taking singular agreement (though I'd probably rephrase to avoid this). 'Mathematics' is certainly now ...

Comment: . . . said to 'function as singular' (and to double 'as singular' **and** 'as plural' in a different sense). Again, terminology is tightened in another Wikipedia article: <<... nouns such as "water" or "furniture," with which only singular verb forms are used because the constituent matter is grammatically nondiscrete (although it may ["water"] or may not ["furniture"] be etically nondiscrete) . . .>> . With food/s, I'd say this 'use singular agreement to signal the notion of a composite whole' (eg 'fish and chips is . . .') usage is productive. 'Pancakes' is possibly a third of the way there.

Comment: Note that '. . .with which only singular verb forms are used because the constituent matter is grammatically nondiscrete . . .' is vacuous, meaning 'we do it that way because that's the way we do it'. The parenthetical paraphrase should be used: '... with which only singular verb forms are used (the constituent matter is "grammatically nondiscrete")' // As an example where the transition from 'regard as plural' to 'regard as singular' seems to have gone well over half way but not the whole hog, we have 'eggs Benedict'. Most of these examples seem food-related.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the ";" and create two separate sentences.  Semi-colons are rarely used, and most people don't know how to use them properly.  The sentence is too long to include a semi-colon, to my belief.  Go to [How to Use Semicolons](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-semicolons) for information on usage.  Semi-colons can be used to keep your writing from having too many short sentences (not an issue there), to emphasize relatedness, to connect a list when some list items have commas in them, among others.

There should be a comma after "grew."  Under most circumstances, unless the clause behind it is very short, there should be a comma before "and."  For example, "colorful labels" is short enough to do without a comma.  It is generally safe to add a comma if in doubt.

[Comma usage rules](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/)

"Pancakes" is not singular.  You can eat a single pancake.  It is generally referred to as pancakes, but that is not the singular form.